# Webgl doesnt run in background

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-chrome, webgl

Im currently developing webgl for PC browser using unity3d. My unity version is 2020.3.30

This webgl project that I made doesnt run when browser is minimized or if i click other tab in same window of this webgl. But at the same time, when i click other window and still window of webgl is in screen so I can see in my monitor, it runs!

and I already setted run in background option to true in player setting, Made it vSyncCount to 0 and targetFrameRate to 0 in Awake in one of the scripts that i run always in game.
I also tried to set targetFrameRate to -1 but i didnt work too...

I know I did something wrong but most of things about this issue that i found just are telling I need to make 'run in background' option to true, which I already set.... And Im using Chrome...

[image: Player Setting]
[image: TargetFramerate]